# Не пойму что не так с редиректами в express

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

Учу ноду и пытаюсь написать простую админку. При редиректе страница открывается только после перезагрузки страницы с ошибкой.

```
//router

Vacancy.findByIdAndUpdate(id, uptadeBody)
.then((vacancy) => {
    req.flash('info', `Вакансия ${vacancy.VacancyId} успешно изменена`);
    res.redirect('/app/admin/vacancy');
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));


//app

const express = require('express');
const session =  require('express-session');
const morgan =  require('morgan');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
const methodOverride =  require('method-override');
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
const passport = require('passport');

const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
app.use('/content', express.static(__dirname + '/content'));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
  secret: '123',
  store: new FileStore(),
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));
app.use(fileupload());
app.use(flash());

require('./libs/passport');
app.use(passport.initialize(), passport.session());

app.use(routes);
module.exports = app;
```

Возможно что-то не то с построением иерархии роутов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// /routers/index

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/app/admin', require('./app'));
router.use('/admin', require('./admin'));
router.use('/api', require('./api'));

module.exports = router;

// /routers/app/index

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/vacancy', require('./vacancy'));
router.use('/place', require('./place'));
router.use('/users', require('./users'));


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Я предположу что пользуешься каким-то руководством? Я так понимаю при редиректе есть ошибка и в консоли браузера можно уточнить ее код? 500 или 404? Это первое на что я бы обратил внимание.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема была в методе хранения сессии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в методе хранения сессии.

Comment: Можешь подробнее расписать какой код ты изменил, после чего все заработало? на случай если люди столкнутся с похожей проблемой?